# Consulta sobre git, ramas y revertir cambios

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

Estoy empezando con GIT y mi duda se daria en el siguiente escenario

commitInicial - creo el archivo1 y el archivo2

commitA - modifico el archivo1 y el archivo2

commitB - añado nuevas modificaciones en el archivo1 y el archivo2

si en el commitB hubiese un error en el archivo2 y tuviese que volver a la versión anterior de ese fichero, que tendría que hacer para dejar 
el archivo1 del commitB y el archivo2 del commit A

Espero haberme explicado correctemante y se entienda mi duda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ git checkout <commit_hash> -- <file>
```

Con este comando podras tener el archivo que quieras en el commit que quieras